# Microsoft Word hangs after BeforeSaveAs with add-in on user PC

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-2010, office-addins

I have a C# 4.0 VSTO add-in for Word which hooks into the `DocumentBeforeSave` (*to remove some custom marks in the document*). This works fine generally but on a very small number of user machines (*running Word 2010 64-bit Windows 7*) the user experiences a hang when they try to **Save As** (*Save works fine, as does auto-save*).

Logging reveals that my code has exited fine so I'm stumped as to what can be causing it. Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Comment: If you disable the add-in does it still hang (*i.e. you know it's your add-in causing the problem*)? If your addin is causing Word to hang - you will have to share your relevant code for context.